# Different formatting for normal and starred chapters

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

I have a problem with the title format.
In particular, I want to use two different formats for the title of my chapters. One for the Introduction, the Conclusion (and the Bibliography). The other one for normal chapters.

I have redefined the title format in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]}    {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc} %provides addchap for standard classes
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


%\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Do you know how to put the title for the Introduction, ... on the left?

Comment: Please see my update to your other question: it can be done using the `numberless` key  of `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you very much Bernard. It works. If you want, you can answer my question here and I will mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `numberless` key for a different chapter formatting, combined with a local change of the value of the `secnumdepth` counter and ordinary chapters:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[clearempty, pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]} {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\LARGE\bfseries\filright}
{} {0pt}
{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\chapter{A First Chapter}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]